# Can't force http over htaccess with cloudflare

Tags: .htaccess, cloudflare

I start to use cloudflare with their flexible SSL.

I made a page rule to auto rewrite the requests for the HTTPS(always use https) like that:

```
http://*example.com/*
```

But it keeps redirecting me as in the loop...
I don't have anything for this in my `.htaccess` or something like that.

I tried to force the HTTP from the origin to the cloudflare like that, but it didn't work(getting unavailble page instead):

```
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) http://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
```

If you have specific to Cloudflare solution for this I would be more than glad to hear it, but if you know **how to force HTTP** via `.htaccess it will be good too.

Answer (score 0):

Use this in your .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =abc.com
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
```